# Ubuntu 20.04 - Encrypt disk without asking password at boot

Tags: encryption

as per title im looking for a "Tutorial for dummies" on how to achieve that.

Can somebody point me in the right direction or explain here how to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Hello. It would depend on what method you used to encrypt. What did you use?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. im  totally ignorant on the matter. i still did nothing. so i dont know witch method to use

Comment: Now that is a totally different question to the one you asked.

Comment: can you elaborate more ? i just asked what i wish to do and how to achieve that. if i did a mistake please tell me so i can update the question

Comment: You asked about not using a password. Then in the comment you asked what is the best one to use. Different questions. On this site it is frowned on to ask opinion questions. Sounds like a good time to fo some Google searches.

Comment: Create a keyfile in `/boot` or on a usb stick that needs to be plugged upon boot and edit your `/etc/crypttab` ... that should already be enough.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try

Answer (score 0):

Go to Disks, then point to encrypted disk partition, select gear "Additional partition options" and there you'll find "Edit Encryption Options" with a required setting